# LibSVM vs. LibShortText

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

What's the difference between using a linear classifier with `LibSVM` vs. using `LibShortText` or `LibLinear`, if there is a difference at all? The same goes for using `SVMlight`; are they implemented differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibShortText is built upon LibLinear and specified in short-text classification.

LibLinear is considered faster than linear LibSVM, and often used for large scale data set. Prof. Lin's website shows [When to use LIBLINEAR but not LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/). The result from LibLinear and LibSVM are considered close to each other when you set `'-b 1'` in LibLinear (note that the bias term is not used by default). The difference between the results even with the added bias is supposed to be due to the regularization term (`w'w+b^2`).

SVMlight is also a good option in large data set classification, and it is especially efficiency in implementation of the leave-one-out cross-validation.

Comment: Thanks @lennon310! Where does SVMlight implement cross validation? Or is it done in the background without asking the user...? I haven't seen any mention of it. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Thank you Cheshie. It's in fact similar with libsvm, -x is the leave one out option. Check Available options in their website: http://svmlight.joachims.org/

Comment: Oops, I guess I missed that before... Thanks!